# Flag declined and question removed later

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation, flag-history

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474160/git-script-to-get-the-information-for-jenkins) for very low quality. Flag was  declined. Fair enough.

But if you check the link above, it turns out that *"This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation"*. I guess that the moderator removing the question was not the same that declined the flag.

Should I get the flag declined removed from my flag history?

Comment: *"for reasons of moderation"* != *"by a moderator"* - it was automatically cleaned up by the [Community user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) due to lack of interest (two downvotes, no answers). See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/248731

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you didn't flag the question as Low Quality, you used a custom "other" moderator flag that said:

> Grammar is poor and there are words that don't exist, like git-om or git-a. It looks like an automatic translation from OP's native language. Should be totally re-written and simply editing wouldn't work.

Moderators should only be involved in things that can't be handled by the community. Based on that flag, what did you want the moderator to do? Edit it? Delete it? If you flag something for a moderator, you need to be specific in what you expect them to do.  Moderators are human exception handlers and in this case, they didn't need to be involved so the flag was declined.

The question has been deleted for the reason `RemoveDeadQuestions` which means it was removed during the cleanup process that runs on the site aka [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Dead questions are removed:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

This question met that criterion so it was deleted, it had nothing to do with your flag. Also deleting the question after your flag was declined doesn't remove the decline from your flag history.

Comment: As a disclaimer, the information regarding removal by Community user is not available to me. I should have tagged the flag as VLQ. Thanks.